# How to add color flowing from bottom to top in svg using css

Tags: html, css, svg, svg-animate

I am a newbiew SVG animator and I am trying to make a logo for my website and I have made four rectangles in Figma and all have different paths. So I am trying to fill the rectangles with a smooth transition which starts from bottom most rectangle to the top most, I want the color to fill like it's a color going from the bottom most to the top most, further I want a different color in every rectangle, so could anyone please help me out.

```css
*{
    padding: 0%;
    margin:  0%;
    box-sizing:  border-box;
}

body{
    width: 100%;
    height:  100%;
    background-color:  rgb(32,35,48);
}

#logo{
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50px, -50px);
    animation: line-fill 5s ease forwards 1.2s;

}

#logo path:nth-child(1){
    stroke-dasharray: 680px;
    stroke-dashoffset: 680px;
    animation: line-anim 2s ease forwards 0.2s;
}
#logo path:nth-child(2){
    stroke-dasharray: 680px;
    stroke-dashoffset: 680px;
    animation: line-anim 2s ease forwards 0.4s;
}
#logo path:nth-child(3){
    stroke-dasharray: 680px;
    stroke-dashoffset: 680px;
    animation: line-anim 2s ease forwards 0.6s;
}
#logo path:nth-child(4){
    stroke-dasharray: 680px;
    stroke-dashoffset: 680px;
    animation: line-anim 2s ease forwards 0.8s;
}

@keyframes line-anim{
    to{
        stroke-dashoffset: 0;       
    }
}

@keyframes line-fill{
    from{
        fill: transparent;
    }
    to{
        fill: white;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    
</head>
<body>
    <svg id="logo" width="291" height="282" viewBox="0 0 291 282" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <path d="M5 225.5H2.5V228V277V279.5H5H286H288.5V277V228V225.5H286H5Z" stroke="white" stroke-width="5"/>
    <path d="M5 2.5H2.5V5V54V56.5H5H286H288.5V54V5V2.5H286H5Z" stroke="white" stroke-width="5"/>
    <path d="M5 76.5H2.5V79V128V130.5H5H286H288.5V128V79V76.5H286H5Z" stroke="white" stroke-width="5"/>
    <path d="M5 150.5H2.5V153V202V204.5H5H286H288.5V202V153V150.5H286H5Z" stroke="white" stroke-width="5"/>
    </svg>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you mean each block to transition in turn to gradually get more color saturation like start light blue and end as a solid darker blue ORr do you mean to fill each with a gradient from like a light blue at the bottom to a dark blue at the top, and one with a light green at bottom and dark green at the top etc.

Comment: This is what I actually meant, I want the color to be less saturated at the bottom and most saturated at the top, you're totally right in your example of Light Blue at bottom and solid darker blue at top, which would make it feel like that the color is actually moving from one block to another.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this method to implement color flow for SVGs:

```html
<svg>
  <rect width="100%" height="100%">
    <animate attributeName="fill" dur="5s" values="pink;purple;pink" repeatCount="indefinite" />
  </rect>
</svg>
```

Comment: This is not working with my code, I am total noob, sorry.